# How to replace storage from MySQL to Elasticsearch to deploy Zipkin Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, zipkin

I am using the Kubernetes to deploy and trace data from application using zipkin. I am facing issue in replacing MySQL with Elasticsearch since I am not able to get the idea. Even the replacement is done on command line basis, using STORAGE_TYPE="Elasticsearch" but how that can be done through kubernetes? I am able to run the container from docker imgaes but is there any way to replace through deployment?

Answer (score 1):

You may define all needed params via ENV options.
Here is a cmd for running zipkin in docker:

```
docker run  -d -p 9411:9411 -e STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch -e ES_HOSTS=http://172.17.0.3:9200 -e ES_USERNAME=elastic -e ES_PASSWORD=changeme openzipkin/zipkin
```

All these params can be defined in Deployment (see [Expose Pod Information to Containers Through Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/))